# Submitting form data after changing values of hidden fields

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have a simple html form:

```
<form id="formD" action="/somewhere" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="i[value]" ng-model="i.value" value={{i.value}}
  <button type="button" ng-click="changevalue()) Change Value
```

With a form controller:

```
function myFormController($scope) 
{
  $scope.saveAsDraft = function(){
    $scope.i.value="true";
    console.log($scope);
    document.getElementById("formD").submit();
  };
}
```

On inspecting the console log, `value` is changing within the `$scope`, but after submitting, `i.value` is always empty! Where am I making a mistake?

Another approach that I took was to make that input field as text:

```
<input type='text' name="i[value]" id="something" 
       ng-model='i.value' style="display:none;">
```

Please help. How can I change the value of this hidden field just before submitting the form data?

Comment: Why are you separating attributes with commas? it is incorrect. You should separate them with spaces only.

Comment: Are those commas literally in the HTML? They shouldn't be there!

Comment: Tch Tch Tch, those commas are there because I wrote them orginally in jade, and just for the sake of clarity I wrote HTML here, forgot to remove commas here, will edit the answer.

Those commas are not the answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

You are separating attributes with commas. That is incorrect. They should be separated with spaces **only**, like in this example:

```
<input type="text" name="i[value]" id="something" 
       ng-model="i.value" style="display:none;">
```